# How to make Firefox/Chrome quit when I close it?

Tags: catalina, google-chrome, firefox

There is a weird issue with Firefox/Chrome browser where if I close it using the red close button, it loses all the opened tabs. If I right click on it in the Dock and "Quit", it remembers the session next time I open it.

So, is there a way to make the "close" button behave as "quit" if the window I’m closing is the last one open?

Comment: That is the exact behavior that is built into *ALL* macOS apps. Only single window apps like music and photos quit when you close the (only) window. It is that way **by design** and the chance you are going to find something to modify that behavior is slim. You may have to just learn to hit COMMAND-Q instead of the little red dot.

Comment: As Steve says, use Cmd/Q. Clicking the red dot is a Windows paradigm. Windows can't tell the difference between Quit & Close. Mac can.

Comment: I don’t care about the inner working of either of those, I’m seeing an issue from the user experience standpoint. I don’t want to lose my session because I close the window instead of quitting the application. It doesn’t make any sense in any possible scenario because it hurts usability. Why for example, Mac doesn’t reopen  the last window instead of serving a brand new with my tabs wiped? What is the usecase they are solving? None, right.

Comment: Re: https://github.com/Drive4ik/simple-tab-groups/issues/716#issuecomment-785504666 as far as I can tell, what's **required** is an enhancement to Firefox. When I have a Bugzilla@Mozilla reference, I'll add it to GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CMD + Shift + T to reopen a window that was accidentally closed and CMD + Shift + N for me just opens a new Incognito window.

I think I have a pretty good solution for you, I hope :) Plus, it will solve another, possibly bigger issue - at least for me.

**History**
I'd curse at my computer multiple times a day, threatening to toss it out of my fifth-floor apartment window  Macbooks are expensive - why am I having to deal with memory issues? Maybe they got their shit together with the new M1 chips this year. I'm saving up slowly for 15" or 16" in 2021.

After putting in real work time with 4 different browsers over the course of about 6 days, noting my device's performance under normal working conditions, and being flexible with workflows in each browser, I came back to Chrome.

I continued searching high and low for an answer to my dilemma with no luck. I ultimately came up with my own little solution, implementing two wonderful plugins. They also added some benefits that I didn't even know I needed, which is something that'll help you automatically saving your windows' state of tabs, while also along you to save collections of tabs manually.

I don't know how I've survived this long...

**"Chrome Tab Hoarder" and "Memory Efficiency" Achievements Unlocked!**
Confession - I knew my memory issues were caused by the fact that I had 15 browser tabs open.

No idea why you're bringing up that I'd save these growing number of tabs to *maybe* look at them a few days later... Whatever! They were important at the time

Get the Toby Chrome extension to automatically save any and all browsing window states whether your computer stroked out or you quit Chrome on purpose. It's even better than what I was originally searching for because you can save (and edit at any point) Collections of tabs. This is by far my most used and favorite thing that I've discovered in 2020 (along with my web design software, Figma, and upgraded web development workflow).

The perfect companion extension for Toby is called The Great Suspender. It will cause you to yell at the sky screaming profanities a lot less because your computer will run SO much better. Suspended tabs use significantly less energy and memory. If you have tabs open and don't use them within 30 minutes, it'll stay there in your tabs, but be suspended and not use resources. When you click on the tab, it reloads. It won't suspend any tabs that have input fields with information in them or ones that actively play videos or sounds. You have options to not suspend any tabs from a particular domain, particular URLs (I don't suspend Gmail, ClickUp, and some others), customize the amount of time before suspending a tab, etc

I hope this helps some people! It may sound like a lot but give it an honest couple of days and see what you think, especially those of us who are tab hoarders/whores/junkies lol.

I literally have 46 tabs open between two different windows - oops  My 3-year-old MacBook Pro has that plus Photoshop and 6 other open apps. My embarrassing number of tabs (let's not talk about it) wasn't even a possibility before, neither was saving them.

Comment: Reopening the last closed window might be not a workaround in cases where the *context* of what was closed can not be reopened by Firefox. This may be true for at least one Mozilla-recommended extension.

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to reopen last closed window.

Comment: I would prefer not to lose my session and keep my tabs open seamlessly. Also, I doubt this works after reboot, but I’ll try.